# Is survey analysis in Stata or R equivalent to a fixed effect generalized linear model?

Tags: r, stata, survey, meta-analysis

I am conducting an individual patient level data meta-analysis using the survey package in R (I tried Stata 13 but I get stuck with an error).

As per meta-analytic practice, I would prefer to conduct both fixed and random effect analyses, but it appears no such option is available with the survey packages in either Stata or R. Briefly, study-level meta-analysis are typically based on a fixed-effect approach (eg Peto) when there is limited statistical inconsistency/heterogeneity. Conversely, a random-effect approach (eg DerSimonian-Laird) is used when inconsistency/heterogeneity is significant or when a more robust (but potentially less sensitive) analysis is sought (see for instance [Kelley and Kelley](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4145560/) for a brief tutorial on study-level meta-analysis).

The approach to patient-level meta-analysis is less established. A common strategy is to conduct analysis in two phases (first analyzing each study as if it was alone), and then combining with study-level meta-analytic methods the study-specific results. This approach, called two-stage, is easily conducted and reasonably robust.

More recently, one-stage approaches have been advocated, in which patient-level modelling takes into account study-level clustering. Several methods have been proposed for this analytical strategy, from conditional regression to generalized linear models or generalized estimating equations (see for instance [Burke et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5297998/)).

I have recognized that the survey packages in Stata and R can perform clustered analysis easily, but I am not sure whether I can specify fixed vs random effect in such models, nor whether I can quantify statistical inconsistency/heterogeneity between studies within such model.

My assumption though is that the survey package provides analyses which are equivalent to those of a generalized linear model or generalizing estimating equations with fixed effects with explicit correlations acknowledge in the model.

Comment: I don't think they are. You can use the lme4 package in R or xtmixed in stata to do random effects models.

Comment: A reproducible example (including the one that produces an error) would help. For the benefit of me... since nobody looked at your question for a month ;)... can you explain the advice regarding both the fixed and random effect approaches to meta-analysis? Keeping in mind that different people mean different things re: fixed/random effects (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27693/5739). Please edit your question above, do not reply below.

Comment: Generally, the functionality of GEE vs. survey is complementary: GEE (attempt to) model correlations that survey just clusters on. But survey can incorporate stratification and other bells and whistles. So I agree with @JeremyMiles: there is no way to say that a particular GEE **exactly** coincides with a given survey-aware estimation command. Unstructured covariance sorts of goes in that direction, but it requires some sort of balance in the data, which survey estimation does not care about.

Comment: @StasK Thanks for the comment. I have substantially revised the question

Comment: I would use lme4 to do a random effects regression in a one stage approach. Why do you need the survey package?